# DGK Cryptosystem Key Generation and Decryption Issues

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption

I detailed [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/dgk-cryptosystem-encryption-speedup) the DGK (Ivan Damgård, Martin Geisler and Mikkel Krøigaard) cryptosystem, and I managed to get it to work, most of the time...

The BIG problem that I am facing at the moment is that the key generation algorithm sometimes produces bad keys. The paper states that:

- we generate $h$ of order $v_p v_q$ modulo p and q
- we generate $g$ of order $u v_pv_q$ modulo p and q

That sounds simple enough, right? But what does it mean? The naive approach (and I'm going to provide it only for $h$, since it works similarly for $g$) is this:

If $h \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ must have order $v_p v_q$, then the following conditions must be met:

- $h^{v_p} \neq 1$
- $h^{v_q} \neq 1$
- $h^{v_p v_q} = 1$
- Must ensure that $h \in \mathbb{Z}_n^* \Rightarrow gcd(h, n) = 1$
- Also, we make sure that $h > 1$

Now, I have tested this approach and it seems to take quite a lot of time to produce a "good" value (perhaps I had an error in the code or I have no idea why it takes forever), so another approach would be to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to obtain $h$ (and $g$):

- Compute $h \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ of order $v_p v_q$ modulo p and q $\Rightarrow h = h_r^{p_r q_r u} \pmod n$, where $h_r$ is a random number in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ and $p_r$, $q_r$ are the random components of p and q. In order to obtain p and q, we choose 2 random primes, $v_p$ and $v_q$ and we compute $p = p_r u v_p + 1$ and $q = q_r u v_q + 1$, such that p and q are prime.
- $n = p q$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^* \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p^* \times \mathbb{Z}_q^*$
- h represented in $\mathbb{Z}_p^* \times \mathbb{Z}_q^*$ is $(h_p, h_q)$
- $h_r$ represented in $\mathbb{Z}_p^* \times \mathbb{Z}_q^*$ is $(h_{rp}, h_{rq})$
- $h^{v_p v_q} \overset{\mathbb{Z}_p^* \times \mathbb{Z}_q^*}{\longleftrightarrow} (h_p^{v_p v_q}, h_q^{v_p v_q}) = ((h_{rp}^{p_r q_r u})^{v_p v_q}, (h_{rq}^{p_r q_r u})^{v_p v_q})$

  - $h_p^{p - 1} = 1 \pmod p$ and $h_q^{q - 1} = 1 \pmod q$
  - $p - 1 = p_r u v_p$ and $ q - 1 = q_r u v_q$
- $(h_p^{v_p v_q}, h_q^{v_p v_q}) = (1^{q_r v_q}, 1^{p_r v_p}) \overset{\mathbb{Z}_n^*}{\longleftrightarrow} 1 \pmod n$

From the above math, it seems obvious that if I choose $h = h_r^{p_r q_r u} \pmod n$, where $h_r$ is a random number and I ensure that $h \in \mathbb{Z}_n^* \Rightarrow \gcd(h, n) = 1$ and $h > 1$, then I should get a "good" $h$ of order $v_p v_q$, but not of order $v_p$ or $v_q$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

Unfortunately, for some reason, this does not work well. I often get $\gcd(p_r q_r u, n) \neq 1$, which means that no matter what is the value of $h_r$, $h_r^{p_r q_r u} \pmod n = 1$. Because of this, I added another condition while generating p and q: $\gcd(p_r, v_p) = 1$ and $\gcd(q_r, v_q) = 1$. Although it seems to avoid the above issue, I am unable to explain it. Also, now I've hit another issue: It looks like I sometimes end up with g of order $v_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, which messes up the decryption algorithm: $E(m,r)^{v_p} = (g^{v_p})^m\pmod p$

Does anybody have any idea how to fix his? I'm almost sure that I have to impose extra conditions while generating p and q, but I am unable to figure it out and it would really be great to understand what exactly is going on... Is there a cleaner way to generate numbers of a certain order modulo n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else is trying to implement this cryptosystem, I wish to share the implementation that I am currently using. Someone helped me pick another approach for generating $ h $ and $ g $, and, intuitively, it seems secure.

In order to generate $ h $ and $ g $, I now apply certain algorithms described in the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)

Specifically, I use **Algorithm 4.83**, Chapter 4: Selecting an element of maximum order in $ \mathbb{Z}_n^* $, where $ n = p q $:

INPUT: two distinct odd primes, $ p $, $ q $, and the factorizations of $ p - 1 $ and $ q - 1 $.

OUTPUT: an element $ \alpha $ of maximum order $ lcm(p - 1; q - 1) $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_n^* $, where $ n = p q $.

1. Use Algorithm 4.80 with $ G = \mathbb{Z}_p^* $ and $ n = p - 1 $ to find a generator $ a $ of $ \mathbb{Z}_p^* $.
2. Use Algorithm 4.80 with $ G = \mathbb{Z}_q^* $ and $ n = q - 1 $ to find a generator $ b $ of $ \mathbb{Z}_q^* $.
3. Use Gauss's algorithm (Algorithm 2.121) to find an integer $ \alpha $, $ 1 \leq \alpha \leq n - 1 $, satisfying $ \alpha \equiv a \pmod p $ and $ \alpha \equiv b \pmod q $.
4. Return $ \alpha $.

For completeness, here are the two algorithms referenced above in Algorithm 4.83:

**Algorithm 4.80**, Chapter 4 : Finding a generator of a cyclic group:

INPUT: a cyclic group $ G $ of order $ n $, and the prime factorization $ n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k} $

OUTPUT: a generator $ \alpha $ of $ G $

1. Choose a random element $ \alpha $ in $ G $
2. For $ i $ from $ 1 $ to $ k $ do the following:

   - Compute $ b \gets a^{n/p_i} $ (N.B. $ \pmod n $)
   - If $ b = 1 $ then go to step 1.
3. Return $ \alpha $.

**Algorithm 2.121**, Chapter 2 (Gauss's algorithm):
The solution $ x $ to the simultaneous congruences in the Chinese Remainder Theorem (Fact 2.120) may be computed as $ \sum_{i = 1}^{k}{a_i N_i M_i \pmod n} $, where $ N_i = n / n_i $ and $ M_i = N_i^{-1} \pmod {n_i} $. These computations can be performed in $ O((\lg n)^2) $ bit operations.

**Fact 2.120**, Chapter 2: (Chinese remainder theorem, CRT) If the integers $ n_1 $, $ n_2 $, ..., $ n_k $ are pairwise relatively prime, then the system of simultaneous congruences

$ x \equiv a_1 \pmod {n_1} $

$ x \equiv a_2 \pmod {n_2} $

$ \vdots $

$ x \equiv a_k \pmod {n_k} $

has a unique solution modulo $ n = n_1 n_2 \cdots n_k $.

In order to apply Algorithm 4.83, we require the factorizations of $ p - 1 $ and $ q - 1 $. The standard approach would be to just factor the random ~200 bit factors $ p_r $ and $ q_r $. On the other hand, assuming that we don't break the security assumptions, we can use $ p_r = 2 p_r' $ and $ q_r = 2 q_r' $, where $ p_r' $ and $ q_r' $ are random primes of the required size. After ensuring that $ p = 2 p_r' v_p u + 1 $ and $ q = 2 q_r' v_q u + 1 $ are also primes, we may compute $ h $ and $ g $ with the above algorithms:

- First, we compute $ h_r $ and $ g_r $ of order $ LCM(p - 1, q - 1) = (p - 1)(q - 1) / GCD(p - 1, q - 1) = 2 u p_r' v_p q_r' v_q $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_n^* $ with Algorithm 4.83
- $ h $ must have order $ v_p v_q $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_n^* $, so we set $ h = h_r^{2 u p_r' q_r'} \pmod n $
- $ g $ must have order $ u v_p v_q $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_n^* $, so we set $ g = g_r^{2 p_r' q_r'} \pmod n $

And that about wraps it up. Please feel free to add comments if more explanations are needed.

PS: The factor $ 2 $ is required for $ p - 1 = 2 p_r' v_p u $ and for $ q - 1 = 2 q_r' v_q u $ because the product of three odd primes is odd, and, thus, by adding one, we get an even number larger than 2, which can't be prime, but both $ p $ and $ q $ need to be prime numbers.