# RSA exercises example

Tags: rsa, public-key

I have doubts about this question

> Consider the following textbook RSA example. Let be p = 7, q = 11 and
>   e = 3. Give a general algorithm for calculating d and run such
>   algorithm with the above inputs.  What is the max integer that can be
>   encrypted? Is there any changes in the answers, if we swap the values
>   of p and q?

I tried to apply RSA in this way:

$p=7$ and $q = 11$ so $n=(pq)$ and $n=77$, therefore $$\phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1) = (7-1)(11-1)= 60$$

Pick $e$ that is $<60$ and isn't coprime (which means I can't use $2,3$ and $5$)

So after that, I'm blocked, and my solution is to choose another coprime, for example $e=7$ in order to have  public-key: $(n,e)= (77,7)$

But I'm wrong somewhere, because if I use $7$ (or another coprime like $11$) I can't compute $d$. 
In fact, for all numbers that I used, for example with $e=7$, if I pick $d=9$ I have $63$ that if I divided for $60$ I have $1$ with rest $3$.

So my questions are these :

- Am I wronging? (where?)
- As a request , can I pick 3, even if it isn't coprime? (because as I saw
  on theory, I need at least a coprime).
- pick $e= p$ or $q$ seams wrong.right?

Comment: You find the inverse of $e$ according to $\phi(n)$ not according to $n$. The inverse can be calculated with ext-GCD.

Comment: $7^{-1} = 43 \bmod 60$ see at [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E-1+%3D+x+mod+60). You cannot choose 3 since the setup will not be a permutation. An example [here](https://www.lri.fr/~fmartignon/documenti/systemesecurite/6-PublicKey.pdf)

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: I'm studying computer security, I have an exam in a few months and I want to understand these topics before the exam (so I'm studying now). This question has already been asked in an old exam task (in 2015). @kelalaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I wrong? (where?)

Yes, there is a small mistake in the way you are computing $d$: you need to compute $d$ as being the inverse of $e$ modulo $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = 60$. So, if you pick $e= 7$ (since you cannot pick $e = 3$ because it would be coprime with $\phi(n)$), you need to compute its inverse modulo (which is typically done using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)). As said in the comment, the modular inverse of $7 \bmod{60}$ is $7^{-1} = 43 \bmod{60}$.

> As a request , can I pick 3, even if it isn't coprime? (because as I saw on theory, I need at least a coprime).

No, picking a value $e$ that is not coprime with $\phi(n)$ does not allow to [guarantee unique decryption of ciphertexts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12256/29574).

Since this is not desirable, it is **required** that $e$ is coprime with $\phi(n)$, which in turn implies that $\gcd(e,p-1)=1=\gcd(e, q-1)$ when using RSA with $n=pq$ for $p,q$ two primes.

> Picking $e=p$ or $q$ seems wrong, right?

Yes, because then you are literally giving away your private key, since anybody can see that $n \bmod e \equiv 0$, which means that $e$ divides $n$! And, let's say you set $e=p$, then it is easy to recover $q$ as well by computing $\frac{n}{e}=q$ and so anybody knowing your public key $(n,e)$ would be able to recover your private key $(p,q,d)$.

Comment: My problem continues to be that calculation of d ... I'm trying to understand The Euclidean Algorithm

Comment: @theantomc: you want to understand the [*Extended* Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures). See [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54477/555) for a more efficient and easier to implement variant.

Comment: @fgrieu Ups, indeed, missing a "not".

Answer (score 3):

> if I use $e=7$ (or another coprime like $11$) I can't compute $d$

You can use $e=7$. When $n$ is [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), a private exponent $d$ will work if (not: only if) $e\;d\equiv1\pmod{\phi(n)}$, that is by definition when $e\;d-1$ is divisible by $\phi(n)$. There are solutions to that if and only if $e$ is coprime with $\phi(n)$. The textbook systematic way to find such $d$ is the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures). See [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54477/555) for a more efficient and easier to implement variant; or [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54623/555) for a "binary" variant.

Note: When $n$ is [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), the necessary and sufficient condition for $d$ to work in RSA is: $e\;d\equiv1\pmod{\lambda(n)}$ (where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)). That simplifies computation of $d$, and typically leads to a smaller one. $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ is required by some RSA standards including FIPS 186-4. When $n$ is the product of distinct primes $p$ and $q$, $\lambda(n)$ can be computed as
$$\begin{align}\lambda(n)&=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)\\&=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{\gcd(p-1,q-1)}\end{align}$$

> Can I pick $e=3$, even if it isn't coprime with $\phi(n)$?

No. It is required that $e$ is coprime with $\phi(n)$ [equivalently: that $\gcd(e,p-1)=1=\gcd(e,q-1)$ ] in order to insure unique decryption of ciphertexts. Otherwise, there will be multiple plaintexts $m\in[0,n)$ leading to the same ciphertext $m^e\bmod n$. In your case $(n,e)=(77,3)$, for example, $m=4$ and $m=15$ would lead to the same ciphertext $64$.

> Picking $e=p$ or $q$ seams wrong

For large $n$, it would be bad to choose $e$ equal to a factor of $n$ (or with any other approximate relation between $e$ and a factor of $n$) since that would allow factoring $n$. But when one deliberately illustrates RSA with a toy $n$ such as $n=77$ which is trivial to factor, choosing $e$ equal to one of the factors is a non-issue. Still, one could use $e=13$ to avoid that special case.

> What is the largest integer that can be encrypted?

In textbook RSA, plaintext and ciphertext space is the integer interval $[0,n)$. The largest integer that can be encrypted (and decrypts correctly) is thus $n-1$. Notice that it is always encrypted to itself, thus trivial to decipher. More generally, textbook RSA is insecure when directly used to encipher data. It is conjectured secure when $p$ and $q$ are large random secret primes, and a random $x$ in the plaintext space $[0,n)$ is enciphered.

Comment: What is the max integer that can be encrypted? is m<n (in my case 77)?