# How does openssh actually choose the public exponent 'e' when generating a RSA key?

Tags: encryption, rsa

What I've read:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12256
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20328

Seems in practice, will first choose an `e`, then choose the 2 big primes `p1` and `p2`.

What I've learned so far:

- `e` is usually between `(2^16, 2^32)`, e.g `2^16 + 1 = 65537`. // **TODO ..** not sure
- `e` should not be too large, otherwise the public-key operation is slow.

I've also try to read openssh [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/), but can't figure out it yet.

---

### Questions

1. How openssh actually choose `e`, when creating a `RSA` key?
2. If possible, can u point out relevant file/functions in the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/).
3. If a software choose a fixed `e` (e.g `65537`) instead of a random value, will that make the RSA key less secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $e=65537$.
2. See [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-rsa.c#L146-L147) and [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/rsa.h#L43).
3. No, using fixed $e$ is the industry standard, and $e=65537$ is a particularly popular choice.

Comment: Addition: for reasons why $e=65537$ is more popular than $e=3$, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8454/555). Notice that the choice of $p$ and $q$ must be compatible with $e$, if that's chosen and frozen first. The reason why sometime it's enforced $e<2^{32}$ is that's there's no much reason to increase $e$ beyond $65537$, and an historical limitation of a Windows API.