# What does Euler's theorem have to do with RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key, number-theory

In RSA we compute e (encryption key) and d (decryption key) $\bmod phi(n)$ and not $\bmod n$, so how come when we get the keys and encrypt and decrypt we use $\bmod n$ not $\bmod phi(n)$ using the following rules:

Encryption:  $C =(m^e) \bmod n$

Decryption: $m = C^d = (m^e)^d \bmod n = m^{e.d} \bmod n = m^1 \bmod n = m \bmod n$

I don't understand how come $e \cdot d=1$ even if its $\bmod n$ not $\bmod phi(n)$? because in reality it doesn't equal to $1$. What I don't understand is how is it; if it doesn't equal to $1$ it will still decipher successfully.

---

Example:

Given $p = 11$, $q = 3$ and $n = 33$, $phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = 20$, $e = 3$ therefore $d = 7$ since $e \cdot d = 1 \bmod phi(n)$

lets encrypt the number $15$

$$C = 15^3 \bmod n= 9$$

$$m = 9^{7} \bmod n=15$$

but

$$9^7 = (15^{3})^7 = 15^{7 \cdot 3}=15^{21} =15 \mod n$$

How is it possible that we deciphered it successfully using only $\bmod n$ and not $\bmod phi(n)$? Therefore $e \cdot d =21$ and not $1$ and still got $m$? I have a feeling that Euler's theorem ($m^{phi(n)}=1 \bmod n$) have something to do with this but I don't know how!

Comment: It is for proof of the correctness! You can live without it because $a^{b \bmod \phi(n)} \mod n = a^b \mod n$. Can you see why?

Comment: @kelalaka im afraid i dont understand how is that possible ?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2894/18298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given $n>1$, let integer $f>0$ be such that for all $m$ in $[0,n)$ with $\gcd(m,n)\ne1$ it hold $m^f\bmod n=1$. One such integer $f$ is the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $n$, $\operatorname{phi}(n)$ aka $\varphi(n)$, $\Phi(n)$ or $\phi(n)$. Among so many Euler theorems, the one in the question likely is about that property of the Euler totient. The smallest such $f$ is $\lambda(n)$, where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Assume $e$ and $d$ have been chosen such that $e\cdot d\bmod f=1$. By definition¹ of what the operator$\bmod$ is when there is no opening parenthesis immediately on it's left, that means: exists integer $k$ such that $e\cdot d=k\cdot f+1$ (and $0\le1<f$, which stands).

Now, assuming $\gcd(m,n)=1$,
$$\begin{align}
\left(m^e\right)^d\bmod n&=m^{e\cdot d}&\bmod n\\
&=m^{k\cdot f+1}&\bmod n\\
&=m^{k\cdot f}\cdot m^1&\bmod n\\
&=m^{f\cdot k}\cdot m&\bmod n\\
&=\left(m^f\right)^k\cdot m&\bmod n\\
&=1^k\cdot m&\bmod n\\
&=1\cdot m&\bmod n\\
&=m&\bmod n\\
\end{align}
$$
We have proven this under the condition $\gcd(m,n)=1$, which is what the [original RSA paper](https://rsa.grieu.fr) does, and many introductions to RSA do. But that happens to be true under a condition not involving $m$: that $n$ is [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1006/555).

This "square-free  $n$" condition is much more satisfying than $\gcd(m,n)=1$ in the context of encryption of arbitrary message $m$, especially when we use artificially small $n$, since then we can't summarily rule out $\gcd(m,n)\ne1$ as unlikely. In the question $n=33$, thus $\gcd(m,n)\ne1$ occurs for $m$ one of $0$, $3$, $6$, $9$, $11$, $12$, $15$, $18$, $21$, $22$, $24$, $27$, $30$, thus including the $m=15$ considered!

---

¹ For integer $s$ and integer $t>0$, equivalent definitions of what the operator$\bmod$ is when there is no opening parenthesis immediately on it's left include

- $s\bmod t$ is the uniquely defined integer $r$ with $0\le r<t$ and $s-r$ a multiple of $t$
- $s\bmod t$ is the uniquely defined integer $r$ with $0\le r<t$ such that exists integer $k$ with $s=k\cdot t+r$
- depending on sign of $s$, $s\bmod t$ is

  - if $s\ge0$, the remainder of the Euclidean division of $s$ by $t$
  - if $s<0$, either

    - $t-((-s)\bmod t)$ if that's not $t$
    - $0$, otherwise

This is not to be confused with the notation² $r\equiv s\pmod t$ with opening parenthesis immediately on the left of$\bmod$, which equivalent definitions include:

- $s-r$ is a multiple of $t$
- exists integer $k$ with $s=k\cdot t+r$

² $r\equiv s\pmod t$ is preferably read with any of the possibly several $\equiv$ on the left of$\pmod t$ read as *congruent* or *equivalent* rather than *equal*, and with a pause where the opening parenthesis is. That pause is to mark that$\pmod t$ qualifies what's been said. It's common to use $=$ instead of $\equiv$, to omit$\pmod t$, or omit the opening parenthesis before$\bmod$. That's also a common cause of confusion when the difference between$\bmod t$ and$\pmod t$ matters, which includes computation of ciphertext in RSA.

Comment: That means exists integer k such that e⋅d=k⋅f+1 i got confused here! and is it possible to work on two modulos in the same equation? e.d=1 is true only under modulo phi(n) not modulo n,  sorry im new to cryptography

Comment: @ezio: For positive integers, $e⋅d=1$ is possible only for $e=1=d$. Please read the new notes 1 and 2 and be careful with notation, RSA is an area where that's critical. Also be aware that when we write $m^{e\cdot d}\bmod n$, the exponent $e\cdot d$ is _not_ modulo $n$ or any other modulo, and can not in general be reduced modulo $n$. The exponent $e\cdot d$ can be reduced under any modulo $f$ that's a non-zero multiple of $\lambda(n)$, including $f=\varphi(n)$.

Comment: sir your first note clicked in my mind as if its the first time i understand something in mathematics objectively, it felt good, thanks sir may allah grant you everything you wish.