# Do Carmichael's and Euler's totient functions in RSA generate the same keys?

Tags: rsa, keys

Starting with the same primes $p$ and $q$ to generate $n=pq$, will Carmichael's totient function and Euler's totient function give the same public key ($e,n$) and private key ($d,n$) in RSA encryption?

If not, are there specific types or range of primes $p$ and $q$ that result in the difference?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Hint: How is $\lambda(n)$ related to $\phi(n)$?  Is it possible for $e$ and $d$ to satisfy $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ but not $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(n)}$, or _vice versa_?  (Write out the congruences as equations about integers.)

Comment: Also consider looking at existing Qs like https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68873/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54280/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33676/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29591/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard definition of *"same"* when applied to cryptographic keys.

There is a precise definition of *equivalent* keys: keys which always yield the same effect when used for their designated usage, e.g. encryption, decryption, signature generation or verification. For example, in [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard), low order bits of key bytes play no role, thus `0123456789ABCDEF` (in hexadecimal) is a key equivalent to `0022446688AACCEE`, if the later is considered valid. In [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm), `0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF` is equivalent to `8123456709ABCDEF8123456709ABCDEF`.

In RSA, Carmichael's and Euler's totient functions generate *equivalent* keys, even though (in the variant of RSA where the private exponent $d$ is generated from the public exponent $e$) the resulting values of $d_\lambda=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ and $d_\varphi=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ often are not equal. Example:$$\begin{align}
n&=5\times11=55\quad&e&=3\\
\lambda(n)&=\operatorname{lcm}(4,10)=20\quad&d_\lambda&=7\\
\varphi(n)&=4\times10=40\quad&d_\varphi&=27
\end{align}$$

In the (original) variant of RSA where the public exponent $e$ is generated from the private exponent $d$, we'd often have different $e_\lambda=d^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ and $e_\varphi=d^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$.

Note: we do not even have a universally accepted definition of *equal* keys. Are two DES keys represented as 16 characters `0123456789ABCDEF` and `0123456789abcdef` equal? Does LF vs CR/LF matter in RSA keys as [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) files?