# Why is RSA encryption performed in mod n, but computation of inverse in $\bmod \varphi(n)$

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic

I am studying the principles of RSA and have come across some unintuitive statements. Lets revisit the RSA algorithm:

**RSA Key Generation**

*Output: public* key: $k_{pub} = (n,e)$ and private key: $k_{pr} = (d)$

1. Choose two large primes $p$ and $q$.
2. Compute $n$ = $pq$.
3. Compute $\varphi(n) = (p−1)(q−1)$.
4. Select the public exponent $e \in \{1,2,\ldots,\varphi(n)−1\}$ such that
   $\gcd(e,\varphi(n)) = 1.$
5. Compute the private key $d$ such that
   $d\cdot e \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$

**Decryption**:
$x=d_{kpr}(y)\equiv y^{d} \bmod n$

**Encryption:**
$y=e_{kpub}(x)\equiv x^{e} \bmod n$

I don't find intuitive on why we perform encryption and decryption in modulus $n$, but compute the inverse of $e$ in modulus $\varphi(n)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** did you see Euler and Fermat's theorems?

Comment: I've seen some theorems I did not fully grasp on intuitive level. When they were used to proof that xˆ(de) = x mod n, that was not intuitive as well.

Answer (score 5):

What's relevant here is that the [Carmichael totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function) $\lambda(n) = \operatorname{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$ is the [exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) of the [multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n), i.e. the smallest positive integer such that $x^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for all $x$.*

This means that if $ed$ is one more than an integer multiple of $\lambda(n)$, i.e. if $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(n)}$ or, equivalently, if $ed = k\lambda(n)+1$ for some integer $k$, then $$x^{ed} = x^{k\lambda(n)+1} = (x^{\lambda(n)})^k x \equiv 1^kx = x \pmod n.$$

(Of course, the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ is itself an integer multiple of $\lambda(n)$, so $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ implies $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(n)}$.)

---

<sup>*) To be precise, $x^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ only holds for $x$ coprime with $n$, since if $x$ shares a prime factor with $n$, it won't be invertible modulo $n$ and no power of it can be congruent to $1$ modulo $n$.  That's why the definition of the modular multiplicative group requires the elements to be coprime to the modulus.  However, the slightly weaker congruence $x^{\lambda(n)+1} \equiv x \pmod n$ *does* hold for all $x$ as long as $n$ is squarefree, and [that's all we really need for RSA.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33676/why-do-we-need-eulers-totient-function-varphin-in-rsa)  Not to mention that finding a positive $x < n$ that's *not* coprime to the modulus $n$ is literally equivalent to factoring $n$.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To get the decrypted value $x^e \pmod n$ of the meesage $x$  you need the [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) : $$a^{\varphi (n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

Replace $a$ with $x$; $$x^{\varphi (n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

Now, take any value as the decryption exponent $d'$ to figure out

$$x^{e\cdot d'} \equiv \;? \pmod{n}$$

Now, consider $e\cdot d' \bmod \varphi (n)$ that is equal to $$ e\cdot d' = k \varphi (n) +t.$$

Pun back into the equation.

$$x^{e\cdot d'} \equiv x^{k \varphi (n) +t} \equiv  x^{k \varphi (n)} x^t \equiv  1^{k} x^t \equiv  x^t \pmod{n} $$

For decryption, you want the $d'$ so that $x^{e\cdot d'} \equiv x \pmod{n}$

For this we need $t=1$ this means that

$$ e\cdot d' \equiv 1 \bmod{\varphi (n)}.$$ i.e. word the inverse.

**Note 1:** RSA is actually defined with Carmichael lambda $\lambda(n)$ See [$\lambda$ versus $\varphi$ in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29591/18298)

**Note 2:** The only cases in which a message $(m,n)\not\equiv 1 $ is when $m$ is $p$ and $q$. RSA works with that, too. One can see this with CRT. See [Does RSA work for any message M?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1004/18298) for details.

Comment:  and  should be coprime. How can one know that the input to be encrypted x, is also coprime with n? I believe n is a product of 2 primes, so it isn't prime.

Comment: The only cases are $p$ and $q$ and RSA works with that, too. See [Does RSA work for any message M?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1006/18298)