# Space needed to store an RSA private key

Tags: rsa

How much space is actually needed to store a $4096$-bit RSA private key? I originally assumed $0.512$ kB since $\frac{4096}{8} = 512$, but then I started to wonder whether it was in hex.

Simply, what's the size of a $4096$-bit private key, and how does it compare to the public key?

Comment: Are you talking about the value $d$, all the RSA parameters, or an actual RSA key file (probably ASN.1 encoded)?

Comment: @ArtjomB., if you store the two primes and the public exponent you are close to 4096.

Comment: If popular algorithms for generation of _p_ and _q_ and selection of _e_ are used, thanks to static bits, even little less than 4096 bits will suffice.

Comment: Actually, if you use a fixed algorithm to generate the key (say, a specific algorithm from FIPS 186-3), you could just store the seed and the key size.  Yes, this would make the process of recovering p, q, d rather expensive; however it makes the stored private key quite small...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the size of a 4096 bit private key?

**It depends.**

The range goes from 512 bytes (only $d$, no formatting, no encoding) up to 5632 (full parameter set, maximal $e$ size, no formatting, hexadecimal encoding) bytes for two-prime RSA. If you also consider multi-prime RSA, the range is *much* wider.

**So what influences the size of the stored private key then?**

1. **How do you encode the stored data?**

   1. No encoding, this will give no increase in storage need
   2. [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), this encodes 3 bytes of data into 4 bytes of encoded data
   3. [Hexadecimal encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), this will encode 1 byte of data into 2 bytes of encoded data
2. **How do yo format your data?**

   1. No formatting, this also means no overhead
   2. [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1), this will give some overhead to make the structures parseable and the overhead *will* increase if you use [XER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Encoding_Rules) instead of [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules), the relevant standard is [PKCS#1 (PDF)](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf) here [as well as](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/space-needed-to-store-an-rsa-private-key/34382?noredirect=1#comment80403_34382) [PKCS#8](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5208.txt) for containers and [PKCS#12 (PDF via Archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327110423/http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/pkcs/files/h11301-wp-pkcs-12v1-1-personal-information-exchange-syntax.pdf) as additional wrapper.
   3. [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_Enhanced_Mail), this will give you some overhead for internal structure and the header and footer of the data block
3. **How much data are you storing?**

   1. The absolute minimum $p$, which will allow you to factor $n$ using simple division and will allow you to later derive $d$ "the usual way". This approach provides optimal storage requriments, assuming you're not willing to run the algorithms from 3. which would reduce the need for stored bits of $p$.
   2. Only the private exponent $d$, which will give you a good storage characteristic, but also requires external supply of the public modulus $n$ and the public exponent $e$ for proper operation
   3. A complete minimalistic approach $(n,p',e)$, this will require you to store $e$, but you can optimize it by hard-coding it as [$F_4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). The technique is to store only a minimalistic amount of information of $p$, but enough to recover $p,q$ as per ["On Factoring Arbitrary Integers with Known Bits" by Herrman and May (PDF)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/374.pdf) and ["Small Solutions to Polynomial Equations, and Low Exponent RSA Vulnerabilities" by Coppersmith (PDF)](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fouque/ens-rennes/coppersmith.pdf) . This reduces the storage requirement to 5120 bits, however I do no recommend this as it is highly non-standard and will give you large interoperability problems for a marginal storage saving.
   4. The [smallest (trivial) complete set](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/space-needed-to-store-an-rsa-private-key/34382?noredirect=1#comment80268_34382) $(p,q,e)$ which will allow you to recover $n$ using standard multiplication and will allow you to recover $d$ the usual way.
   5. A [middle-ground minimum](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/space-needed-to-store-an-rsa-private-key/34382#comment80219_34382) $(n,d)$, this will not allow you to factor $n$ without external supply of $e$ (which may be an agreed-upon constant), but is enough to decrypt messages "classically"
   6. Only the bare minimum $(n,e,d)$, this will [allow you factor $n$ somewhat quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5747013/4733946) if needed and it will allow you to do all operations without external data supply
   7. A middle ground amount of data $(n,e,d,p,q)$, this will take away the "heavy" step of factoring $n$ but still leaves some computations to be done if you want [that speed-up from the CRT](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2580/23623).
   8. The full set $(n,e,d,p,q,d_p,d_q,q_{\text{inv}})$, this allows you to load the data and outright start with the computations, including the CRT speed-up

> How does it compare to the public key?

Look at the above list of influencial factors and adapt the third major point, a public key "only" has the option $(n,e)$ there, meaning it *can* be larger than the private key or it can be significantly smaller, if you include the associated data in the private key.

Comment: [This paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/374.pdf) gives better storage size. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, so, am I reading this right that you want to store $n$ and *a very small part* of $p$ and / or $q$ to use the proposed advanced algorithm to recover $p,q$ and hence $d$?

Comment: No, I'm just saying one _can_ do that. ​ ​

Comment: Why are you calling storing $d$ optimal? Since you assume knowledge of the public key, you might as well just store $p$, which halves the space requirements compared to $d$ (and as Ricky points out this could be optimized further, but that adds complexity). If you don't assume knowledge of the public key, I'd store $e,p,q$.

Comment: I'd call PEM an encoding (of DER), extending base64. My alternatives for format would be PGP (mostly bitcount+unsigned, P Q Pinv (because Q>P) but not dP dQ, usually encrypted) and recent OpenSSH (header including some strings then bytecount+signed, similarly except Qinv, usually encrypted, all in PEM), and under ASN.1 also PKCS#8 *containing* PKCS#1 sometimes encrypted -- and maybe even PKCS#12 containing PKCS#8 containing PKCS#1 (almost) always encrypted.