# What information is needed to be stored for RSA private key for decryption

Tags: rsa, public-key

I am using `rsa` module in Python. I use the following line to generate public and private key:

```
(public_key, private_key) = rsa.newkeys(2048)
```

And then I encrypt a message using:

```
encrypted_msg = rsa.encrypt(the_msg, public_key)
```

Now assume I want to give the private key to someone, along with the encrypted message. What information shall be included in the private key that I give to the other person? If I look at the `PrivateKey` structure in Python code, I see that for example `private_key` has the following fields:

`blindfac`, `blinffac_inverse`, `coef`, `d`, `e`, `exp1`, `exp2`, `mutex`, `n`, `p`, `q`.

Do I need to save and pass all these data to the other person so s/he can decrypt the message? What are all these variables?

Comment: In raw RSA, the public key is (n, e) and the private key is (n, d). All the other variables are not needed for the math. But a particular software implementation might make heavy use of the other variables for speed, extra features, and other reasons.

Comment: @Nayuki thanks for the response. Is the variable `n` the same for public and private keys? If it is then one only needs to pass `d` as a private key? Also, what are the other variables I mentioned in the question? Is there a reference that explains those variables?

Comment: (n = p * q) is indeed shared for both the public and private keys. Again, I said that the other variables are implementation-specific and you need to do your own reading.

Comment: "Now assume I want to give the private key to someone, along with the encrypted message." WHY‽ NEVER share a private key, that defeats the point of using RSA. Have the other person generate a key pair and give you their public key. Or better yet, use [age](https://age-encryption.org) to get some major security benefits over encrypting messages with RSA (it's almost always a bad idea to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RSA, there are various numbers that are (kind of) equivalent to the private key, but aren't the private key *per se*.  These are numbers that if you know them, you can calculate the rest of the private key quickly.  Some of these numbers improve signing/decryption speed of the private key if you know them, so RSA implementations often keep them with the private key for speed.

I looked up this implementation and found the following meaning:

- `n` is the *modulus*, the number modulo which key operations are done.
- `e` is the *public exponent*, the power to which a message is taken to encrypt it (or validate its signature).
- `d` is the *private exponent*.  Taking a number to power `d` (modulo `n`) is the inverse operation to taking a number to power `e`.  This is because in RSA, for any $m$ in range, $(m^e)^d \equiv (m^d)^e \equiv m \pmod n$.
- `p` is the *larger factor of `n`*.
- `q` is the *smaller factor of `n`*.  The fact that it's smaller is important to the meaning of `coef`.
- `exp1` is $d \mod (p-1)$.
- `exp2` is $d \mod (q-1)$.
- `coef` is $q^{-1} \mod p$.  It's the *coefficient* for the CRT speedup technique.
- `blindfac` is a random number chosen during decryption or signing.  It is used during these operations to hide the value of private numbers from timing and power attacks: to "blind" timing attacks.
- `blindfac_inverse` is the inverse of `blindfac` modulo `n`, used for the blinding process.
- `mutex` is internal to the implementation, and isn't a number.  It appears to be used for thread-safety of the implementation.

The public key consists of the numbers `n` and `e`.

The private key consists of the numbers `n` and `d`; `e` is usually included for convenience.  You can do all operations with just `d` and the public key, but it may not have optimal performance.

`p`, `q`, `exp1`, `exp2`, and `coef` are additional **private** numbers that, when provided, speed up RSA decryption and signing operations.  You want to keep these numbers if you can, but they are not *necessary*.  For more information on what these do: [Chinese Remainder Theorem and RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/chinese-remainder-theorem-and-rsa)

`blindfac` and `blindfac_inverse` are temporary numbers generated by the `blind()` function in that Python RSA implementation.  Do not save these numbers.

Comment: Thanks that is a great answer. Can you please add some references for completeness? Where did you find the explanation for these parameters?

Comment: @user9278661 Hmm.  I just knew how they were used, and the "CRT and RSA" link is a reference for the extra numbers.  This is all very generic RSA stuff and not specific to python-rsa.  For understanding the particular variable names, I looked up the python-rsa source code: https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/blob/main/rsa/key.py