Proof of Decryption in a Chinese Remainder Theorem-Based Encryption Scheme
I've been studying a cryptographic scheme that uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) for decryption. Here's a brief overview of the encryption and decryption process:
Setup:
Alice chooses two distinct prime numbers, p and q She ensures
gcd(p, q) = 1, gcd(p,q-1)=1, gcd⁡(p−1,q)=1

Alice computes N=pq and publishes it.
Alice calculates
q’ such that q.q’≡1(mod p−1)
p’ such that p.p’≡1(mod q−1 )

Encryption:
Bob encrypts a message M as C=M^N mod  N
Decryption:
Alice decrypts C by finding M′:
M′ ≡   C^q’ (mod p  ) 
M′ ≡   C^p’ (mod q  ) 

By Using the Chinese Remainder Alice Obtain that M = M′
My Question:
Explain  Why does the decrypted message M′ exist and why is it equal to the original message M?
If  possible write mathematical proof
I'm a computer science student 3rd year . I have studied the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem, which seem to be key to understanding this proof. However, I'm struggling to remember how to solve this problem after hours of failed attempted,
So  i  could use the help

Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/chinese-remainder-theorem-and-rsa

Could you possibly outline your failed attempts?  We should be able to point out where you went wrong (we dislike just giving the answers to homework questions; we will give hints).  BTW: you are correct that CRT and FLT are, in fact, keys to understanding this.

@poncho yes i see the related now ,  i know its dislikable to just provide the answer -- but strictly what i have done  where tries and fails with pen and paper
i will check the related discussion in hope i could understand something out of it
thank you

This very cryptosystem and computation method was described by Cliff Cocks in a then secret note of November 1973.
